# delete from database after deleting from the table ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I made a small app using ADF which is deleting row from a table after daraging it to a small picture (recycle bin) on the page 
but now i want this delete to be commited on database 
how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Which JDeveloper version are you using?
You should just be able to drag and drop a commit button from the 'Data Controls' tab > your Data Control > 'Operations' > Commit onto your page.

Or you could do it via a bean (make sure the Commit binding is on your page/fragment). Here is an good example: http://adfsonal.blogspot.be/2013/02/perform-delete-and-commit-by-single.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Key k =EntityImpl.createPrimaryKey(attribute);
        EntityImpl rw =
        (EntityImpl)EntityImpl.getDefinitionObject().findByPrimaryKey(getDBTransaction(), k);
        rw.remove();
        this.getDBTransaction().commit();
```